# Webpack bundle imported modules into dynamic import

Tags: javascript, webpack

i use a dynamic import for a file i use in my Project:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "my-file" */ './my-file').then((module) => { 
   // Code
});
```

Inside of `my-file.js` i use something like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

now i want my `my-file.js` to include the code from `my-file.js` and the `lodash` libary, but i always get 2 files, `my-file.js` and `667.js` (including lodash library). is there a way to get the code all into 1 file?

Answer (score 0):

Try magic comment /* webpackMode: "eager" */
This eager webpack mode will add any new chunk to the current chunk.

See https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import

Comment: This will disable generating chunk for `my-file.js` as well. See the link that you've attached:

> 'eager': Generates no extra chunk. All modules are included in the current chunk and no additional network requests are made. A Promise is still returned but is already resolved. In contrast to a static import, the module isn't executed until the call to import() is made.